# branches with mutliple local users on same git folder

Tags: git, salt-stack

Myself and a colleague are using saltstack (configuration managment framework) for a webstack cluster of about 50 servers. The main directory of the salt-master (master server who controls all infrastructure servers) where all of our config files reside  is managed with git. We push changes from our local repos to the origin/master and then pull on salt-master.

This works pretty well however we have an issue when there are times where we create new files, test, make changes, test again until we are happy with the final result and push on the origin/master. Pushing, pulling and creating 30 commits for just testing until the code finally ends up in a working state is not very reliable.

What we do, is to work on salt-master (main server), make modifications on code, and when we finally observe that everything works as expected we then push to origin/master (from salt-master server). This poses another problem since there are many times where someone is working on the salt-master dir and someone else has pushed from his local machine and wants to pull and execute code in salt-master.

We tried branches however we all "su -" in salt-master so we eventually land as root on the branch where a colleague is working on. Changing to a new branch will result changing the other user working on a different branch to the one just created.

Is there a way somehow, to be able to work on a git folder where other users work in the same folder in different branches without interfering with each other?

Comment: Try `git worktree`. But I think it's better to have a central repository and some development repositories. Every member has his/her own repository. You can push and pull between your own repository and the central repository, and even between any two. https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows The workflows are feasible on the same machine for a group of developers.

Comment: @ElpieKay The central/development repositories sounds nice but the problem is that the master server (salt-master) is the one who controls all other servers. And when you want to test the "saltstack code" we must executed from this single machine from a specificic directory (where CMF software expects to find the files to use in order to configure servers).